# Is there a website dedicated to the application of Category Theory to different branches of Mathematics?

Tags: category-theory, online-resources

For example, if I wanted to know what the product/coproduct is in a certain category, I could find it on that site.  I commonly come across websites (such as wikipedia) that give a few examples of some categorical concept.  I would like a site with a large database which is constantly updated.

Comment: This topic was discussed on the [nForum](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/3884/categories-fact-sheet/) a few weeks ago.